# Airflow appending custom data to email alert

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I want to append a runbook url to the airflow email alerts on failure. The default email sends other useful information such as airflow log link and I dont want to loose that. How can I achieve this.

I explored email operator but seems like it creates a new email and now I get 2 emails one for dag that failed and other from the email operator.

Is there a way to go about it ?

```
failure_email = EmailOperator (
            task_id='failure-email',
            name='failure-email',

            to=['oncall@gmail.com'],
            subject="T3 Failed",
            html_content='<a>https://path/to/runbook</a>',
            namespace= ,
            dag=dag

        )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can customize the airflow email content by setting the `html_content_template` variable in the conf, the value of this var should be a path to a jinja2 file.

for example:

airflow.cfg -

```
[email]
html_content_template = /path/to/template
```

/path/to/template -

```
Try {{try_number}} out of {{max_tries + 1}}<br>
Exception:<br>{{exception_html}}<br>
Log: <a href="{{ti.log_url}}">Link</a><br>
Host: {{ti.hostname}}<br>
Log file: {{ti.log_filepath}}<br>
Mark success: <a href="{{ti.mark_success_url}}">Link</a><br>
Runbook: <a>https://path/to/runbook</a>
```

(The default content of the airflow emails was taken from https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6e269570cd6dd2d434a3c63ca0db9f1a59dea847/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1263).

Comment: Hi @Zacharya, am using airflow version 2.2.5 and try to use the custom template for email content. have created a file and mapped the path to the above mentioned variable but its not working.

Comment: @Manigandan you should remove the `Log file: {{ti.log_filepath}}<br>` line, as `log_filepath` field is not present in task instance anymore.

Comment: I am no longer an Airflow user, so I would know... But I'll accept an edit request if this is the case.